# Circuit with a voltmeter across a resistor

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

[image]

Can someone please answer this question?

Consider the circuit where the voltmeter read 2.8V across a resistor.

Which of these statements is definitely correct?

1. Each electron transfers 2.8J of energy to the resistor.
2. Each coulomb of charge transfers 2.8J of energy to the resistor.

Comment: This is homework.  What have you tried?  What do you know about energy, voltage, and current?

Answer (score 0):

All of the possible answers involve energy.

Start with the definition of energy in an electrical circuit:

$$E = V \times I \times t$$

Where:

- \$E\$ is energy in joules
- \$V\$ is voltage in volts
- \$I\$ is current in amperes
- \$t\$ is time in seconds

You are given:

- Volts
- Charge in coulombs (in two of the answers)
- Electrons

You need to find energy, so you need:

- \$V\$
- \$I\$
- \$t\$

There's nothing there about electrons, so I'll eliminate those answers.

Volts are given.  Where will you get \$I\$ and \$t\$?

From the [coulomb.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb)

One coulomb is 1 ampere for one second.  There's your \$I\$ and your \$t\$.  Fit them into the energy equation along with the given voltage, and you will see how much energy is transferred.

Now, for the direction, a final hint:

A battery provides energy, a resistor does not.

Comment: _You need to find energy, so you need:..I, t"_ - not quite. When relating charge to energy only voltage is needed. The I and t terms cancel out. The circuit could transfer 1 coulomb of charge at 2.8V in 1 picosecond or 1 year, and it would still be 2.8 Joules of energy.

Answer (score -3):

J stand for joule
V stand for volt (abbreviation from voltage)

which is very different.
your statement both false.

because you need more parameters to calculate joule, like current or power (watt) or resistance (ohm) etc.

Comment: _"you need more parameters to calculate joule, like amperage or power (watt) or resistance"_ - No. Joule is a unit of _energy_, which exists independently of time. None of the statements say anything about the time taken to transfer the energy or charge, therefore the power, current, and resistance is irrelevant.

Comment: @XCSource:  Check the definition of [coulomb.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb)  It is mentioned in the question, and gives you the missing information.

Comment: @bruceabbot i know joule is unit of energy.. your statement is irrelevant too, which is even if you know 1000V at 100second doesn't mean you know how much joule, correct? therefore you need to know another parameter. which is you can calculate from there.

Comment: The voltage is known to be 2.8V, not 1000V. The statements relate charge and energy, with no time period specified or implied. You know the Joules because it is stated. The only thing to calculate is how much charge at 2.8V is required to get it (either 1 coulomb or the charge on an electron). Watts, Amps, Ohms ere irrelevant to this relationship. The resistance - and therefore current and power - could be _anything_ and one of the statements would still be true. You do not need to know them to choose the correct answer.

Comment: @bruceabbot bruhh that's what i meant.. "you need more parameter to calculate joule ..... etc"

Comment: No, you are saying the opposite. I am saying you do _not_ need more parameters.

Comment: The name of the unit **volt** is not an abbreviation of *voltage*, it is an abbreviation of *Volta*, a person's name.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for helping me I calculated the answer but my problem was I was confused if an electron transfers energy or 1 coulomb of charge transfers energy but you guys cleared it out so thank you again.